# How to resolve MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=multipart/form-data error

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-client

How to configure provider for simple multi-form post. Any suggestions/pointers would be much appreciated.

Stacktrace:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=multipart/form-data, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:433)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.internal.InMemoryConnector.apply(InMemoryConnector.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:655)
```

pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The Code:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Form;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestMultiPartTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig(ServerSideResource.class);
        rc.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        return rc;
    }

    @Path("test")
    public static class ServerSideResource {

        @POST
        @Path("/multipart")
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response file(FormDataMultiPart formParams) {
            System.out.println("found multipart resource");
            return Response.ok().build();
        }

        @POST
        @Path("/encoded")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response file(Form formParams) {
            System.out.println("found encoded resource");
            return Response.ok().build();
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testPostMultiPartFile() {
        final WebTarget target = target().path("test/multipart");
        final FormDataMultiPart mp = new FormDataMultiPart();
        final FormDataBodyPart p = new FormDataBodyPart("field1", "CONTENT ONE");
        mp.bodyPart(p);
        final FormDataBodyPart p2 = new FormDataBodyPart("field2", "CONTENT TWO");
        mp.bodyPart(p2);

        System.out.println("making multipart request");
        final Response r = target.request().post(Entity.entity(mp, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE), Response.class);
        System.out.println(r.getStatus());
        assertThat("response is 200", r.getStatus(), is(200));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPostEncodedForm() {
        final WebTarget target = target().path("test/encoded");
        final Form form = new Form();
        form.param("test", "value");
        System.out.println("making encoded request");

        final Response r = target.request().post(Entity.form(form), Response.class);
        System.out.println(r.getStatus());
        assertThat("response is 200", r.getStatus(), is(200));
    }

}
```

Comment: I have explained [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504202/1909241)

Answer (score 53):

Well, reading the documentation was not helpful but reading the jersey integration tests source code was.

In the JerseyTest instance you need to override the configureClient method and pass in the MultiPartFeature class.

```
@Override
protected void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
    config.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
}
```

Working Code:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Form;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestMultiPartTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig(ServerSideResource.class);
        rc.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        return rc;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
        config.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    }

    @Path("test")
    public static class ServerSideResource {

        @POST
        @Path("/multipart")
        @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        // @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response file(FormDataMultiPart formParams) {
            System.out.println("found multipart resource");
            return Response.ok().build();
        }

        @POST
        @Path("/encoded")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        // @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response file(@FormParam("field3") String field3) {
            System.out.println("found encoded resource");
            System.out.println("got form.field3 value: " + field3);
            return Response.ok().build();
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testAnotherWay() {
        WebTarget target = target("test/encoded");
        final Form form = new Form();
        form.param("field3", "field3 value");
        System.out.println("testAnotherWay");
        Response response = target.request().post(Entity.form(form), Response.class);
        System.out.println(response);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPostMultiPartFile() {
        final WebTarget target = target().path("test/multipart");
        final FormDataMultiPart mp = new FormDataMultiPart();
        final FormDataBodyPart p = new FormDataBodyPart("field1", "CONTENT ONE");
        mp.bodyPart(p);
        final FormDataBodyPart p2 = new FormDataBodyPart("field2", "CONTENT TWO");
        mp.bodyPart(p2);

        System.out.println("field1: " + mp.getField("field1").getValue());
        System.out.println("field2: " + mp.getField("field2").getValue());
        System.out.println("making multipart request");
        final Response r = target.request().post(Entity.entity(mp, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), Response.class);
        System.out.println(r);
        assertThat("response is 200", r.getStatus(), is(200));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPostEncodedForm() {
        final WebTarget target = target().path("test/encoded");
        final Form form = new Form();
        form.param("field3", "field3 value");
        System.out.println("making encoded request");

        final Response r = target.request().post(Entity.form(form), Response.class);
        System.out.println(r);
        assertThat("response is 200", r.getStatus(), is(200));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you mate. For me the key was this overridden method:

@Override
protected void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
    config.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
}

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on the client side instead, as I was, and using Jersey 1.X, the answer by **angstadt530** on this page is what you need.

[Jersey client exception: A message body writer was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585074/jersey-client-exception-a-message-body-writer-was-not-found)

```
DefaultClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getClasses().add(MultiPartWriter.class);
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
```

is how it looks in my code, but the example on that page is excellent as well.