# jersey-client MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: jersey-client

Using org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-client version 2.16 and can't seem to make a simple POST request:

MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**client**

```
String response = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://0.0.0.0:8080")
        .path("/get")
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
        .post(Entity.entity(getForm(), MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE), String.class);

private Form getForm()
{
    return new Form() {{ this.param("whatever", "whatever"); }};
}
```

**server**

```
@Path("/get")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String postForToken(@FormParam("whatever") final String whatever) {...}
```

Registering a MultiPartFeature as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668426/how-to-resolve-messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-type-multipart-form-data-er) post makes no difference.

```
config.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the clue was in the full exception message (not posted above).

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, type=class com.blah.AcceptanceTest$1, genericType=class com.blah.AcceptanceTest$1.
```

The $1 indicates it's trying to resolve some sort of inner class - which led me to the anonymous subclass of Form. Changing the above to the following works fine:

```
private Form getForm()
{
    final Form form = new Form();
    form.param("whatever", "whatever");
    return form;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jersey uses [Entity Providers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html) to serialize and de-serialize Java objects — it uses `MessageBodyWriter` to serialize and `MessageBodyReader` to de-serialize.  Some entity providers are available out-of-the-box, including the `FormProvider`, which handles both reading and writing of `Form` objects that are of media type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

[Section 8.3](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#providers-selection) of the Jersey documentation outlines the algorithm used when deciding which registered Provider to use.  Step 5 says this:

> 5. Iterate through the sorted MessageBodyWriter providers and,
>      utilizing the isWriteable method of each until you find a
>      MessageBodyWriter that returns true.

The problem is that the [implementation of `isWriteable()`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.16/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/FormProvider.java#L99) in `FormProvider` checks to see if the runtime type of the object is **exactly** equal to `Form.class` -- subclasses, including anonymous classes, do not qualify, so the method returns `false` and the `FormProvider` is not used for serialization.  Then, no other matching providers are found, and the result is a `MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException`.

**The Easy Solution:**

The easy solution is to just use an actual `Form` class.

**The Hard Solution:**

For anyone who really wants to use subclasses of `Form`, the hard solution would be to reimplement `FormProvider` (it's marked `final`, so you can't just subclass it), substituting the following code for the `isWriteable()` method:

```java
public boolean isWriteable(...) {
    return Form.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
}
```

Then you'd have to register your custom FormProvider with the `Client` before you use it:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(MyFormProvider.class);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your "Easy Solution".

Comment: @Christian - The FormProvider is looking for an object that is exactly an instance of Form -- subclasses of Form won't match. So if you can get by with using an instance of Form itself, without subclassing it, that would be much less involved than creating your own provider.