# REST API: How to make a `POST` call in `JSON` using Java?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jersey

I am very new to making REST APIs. I am using `Jersy` to make the APIs. Below is the code for the REST API

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

/**
 *
 * @author Yohan
 */
@Path("/json/metallica")
public class JsonService {

    @GET
    @Path("/getTrackInJSON")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Track getTrackInJSON() {

        Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
        track.setSinger("Metallica");

        return track;

    }

        @GET
    @Path("/getTrackArray")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ArrayList<Track> getTrackArray() {

            ArrayList<Track> list = new ArrayList<Track>();

            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman: "+i);
        track.setSinger("Metallica");

                list.add(track);
            }


        return list;

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void createTrackInJSON(Track track) {

        String result = "Track saved : " + track;
                System.out.println(result);


    }

}
```

Now, I have tried the `GET` commands, now need to try the `POST` commands. I wrote the below code, in a seperate package of the same project.

```
import com.tutorialspoint.Track;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


public class JerseyClientPost {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
                WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/RESTFUL_API_SAMPLE/rest/json/metallica/").path("/post");

                Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman: ");
        track.setSinger("Metallica");
                Track bean =
target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
    .post(Entity.entity(track,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE),
        Track.class);


      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }
}
```

Now I get the following error.

```
Feb 02, 2016 11:11:02 AM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, type=class com.tutorialspoint.Track, genericType=class com.tutorialspoint.Track.
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, type=class com.tutorialspoint.Track, genericType=class com.tutorialspoint.Track.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:502)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:448)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:349)
    at JerseyClientPost.main(JerseyClientPost.java:38)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

What has happend here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set incorrectly the `POST` media type. Should be `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE` instead of `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE`. As a result Jersey is complaining that it is unable to serialize your `Track` object.

I have not tested this code but you can try something like this:

```
target.request().post(Entity.json(track));
```

Comment: The `POST` method do not return anything. It is `void`

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's break down your error message:

```
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded, 
  type=class com.tutorialspoint.Track, 
  genericType=class com.tutorialspoint.Track.
```

This looks OK:

```
.post(Entity.entity(track,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE), Track.class)
```

Q: Are the class files for everything in package com.tutorialspoint.* (including Track.class) in your build?  In the correct subdirectory (com/tutorialspoint/)?

Q: Is "Track" a subclass of "Form"?  Can you return an actual "Form" object?

Look at this post:

[jersey-client MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969110/jersey-client-messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-type-application-x-www-form)

Comment: The `POST` method do not return anything. It is `void`