# How to fix MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException when passing a MultipartFile to the server

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, gradle, multipartform-data

I've been trying to pass MultipartFiles to my server for 2 days now with no success. My project uses the Springboot framework and gradle to build and I just can't find a solution for MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException:

```
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=multipart/form-data, type=class org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile, genericType=class org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1116)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:443)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:369)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=multipart/form-data, type=class org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile, genericType=class org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile.

    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$2(JerseyInvocation.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.call(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$runInScope$3(JerseyInvocation.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.runInScope(JerseyInvocation.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:686)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:357)
    at client.utils.ServerUtils.filePostRequest(ServerUtils.java:273)
    at client.utils.ServerUtils.saveFile(ServerUtils.java:278)
    at client.scenes.MediaPlayerCtrl.save(MediaPlayerCtrl.java:121)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 57 more
```

I followed the fix from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668426/how-to-resolve-messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-type-multipart-form-data-er) which meant overriding the default jersey config register method, but it didn't work. That is probably because the config change is in the Test side, although I'm not sure.

```
public class FileControllerTest extends JerseyTest {
    @Override
    protected void configureClient(ClientConfig conf) {
        conf.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    }
    @Test
    public void testUploadFile() {assertEquals(1,1);}
}
```

After getting that to work (a lot of depency version incompatibilities), I'm still getting the same MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException. I also tried different conversion methods from the FIle object to MultipartFile, but, as you might've guessed, that didn't work either. I'll put down below the method that's making the call to the server and the server controller:

```
    private <T> void filePostRequest(String path, Entity send, GenericType<T> retType) {
        ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig())
                .target(getServer()).path(path)
                .request("multipart/form-data")
                .post(send, retType);
    }

    public void saveFile(File file) throws IOException {
        MultipartFile file1=convertFileToMultipartFile(file);
        filePostRequest("secure/" + store.accessStore().getUsername() + "/file/add",
                Entity.entity(file1, "multipart/form-data"), new GenericType<>(){});
    }
    public static MultipartFile convertFileToMultipartFile(File file) throws IOException {
        return new MultipartFile() {
            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return file.getName();
            }
            @Override
            public String getOriginalFilename() {
                return file.getName();
            }
            @Override
            public String getContentType() {
                String extension = file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase();
                switch (extension) {
                    case "mp4":
                        return "video/mp4";
                    case "mp3":
                        return "audio/mpeg";
                    case "wav":
                        return "audio/wav";
                    case "jpg":
                    case "jpeg":
                        return "image/jpeg";
                    case "png":
                        return "image/png";
                    default:
                        return "application/octet-stream";
                }
            }
            @Override
            public boolean isEmpty() {
                return !file.exists() || file.length() == 0;
            }
            @Override
            public long getSize() {
                return file.length();
            }
            @Override
            public byte[] getBytes() throws IOException {
                try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                    return inputStream.readAllBytes();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                return new FileInputStream(file);
            }
            @Override
            public void transferTo(File file) throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = {"/secure/{username}/{password}/file", "/secure/{username}/file"})
public class FileController {
    @Autowired
    private StorageService service;
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String uploadFile = service.uploadFile(file);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(uploadFile);
    }
```